# ggplot: density plot error

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I am trying to plot some density plots overlaid on each other using ggplot

```
ggplot(den2, aes(x = V1,y=V2, fill = lines)) + geom_density()
```

However I'm getting this error:
Error in if (nrow(layer_data) == 0) return() : argument is of length zero

Can someone tell me whats going wrong? Data den2 can be found here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByW0yQz1oPLZNV93UVlrSXF0X28/view?usp=sharing

Thanks!!

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563864/ggplot2-overlay-density-plots-r) looks like it has some useful information for you. As the answerer said, the key point is that a density plot is a univariate thing, so you do it for one variable at a time (but possibly with grouping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ggplot(den2, aes(x=V1, y=V2, fill=factor(lines))) + geom_polygon(alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

For 1-D density plots, you just supply one variable, like you would to a histogram.  So, you could do something like this instead,

```
ggplot(den2, aes(x=V1, fill=factor(lines))) + geom_density(alpha=0.5)
```