# How to superimpose density plots ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to superimpose density plots with `ggplot2`. The question has been addressed already [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563864/ggplot2-overlay-density-plots-r) and [Here](https://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/16/ggplot2-plotting-two-or-more-overlapping-density-plots-on-the-same-graph/)

However, even if I use pretty much the same code, I get **stacked** density plots while I'd like them to be superimposing one another.

Here is my code :

```
ggplot(results_groupes.df) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = score_confiance, group = pro_vd, colour = pro_vd)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0,1))
```

And here is what I get :

[image: Density plot]

Any idea what might be my problem ? Maybe in the setups of `ggplot2` ?

EDIT :

Here is the head of the dataframe :

```
structure(list(score_confiance = c(0.0348328535272003, 0.0443069899046832, 
0.0902377811277357, 0.0799802812655336, 0.189541356769244, 0.0443069899046832, 
0.0348328535272003, 0.105242468438049, 0.0860492857517866, 0.0543928293220421, 
0.105845820536651, 0.0909859139609319, 0, 0.122066723148796, 
0.195092913054128, 0.088737794288937, 0.0611340636419152, 0.128808048932376, 
0.0982946374365981, 0.114993650891164, 0.0404376239050328, 0.0482497909637164, 
0.0348328535272003, 0.0239697213961542, 0.045073427806824, 0.122463095753082, 
0.112239171616912, 0.0348328535272003, 0.105242468438049, 0.0443069899046832
), pro_vd = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), .Names = c("score_confiance", 
"pro_vd"), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

EDIT 2 :

Actually one of the densities has a very long, flat tail. Hence the impression that the densities are flat but they are not.

Comment: please give your data or a toy dataset : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am actually having this problem with any dataset that I use... But will try and add one shortly.

Comment: Map the fill to pro_vd and you will see they are superimposed. (Set alpha below 1)

Comment: Is your dataset in long format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(head(results_groupes.df, 30))`.

Comment: I have added the head of my dataframe. 

@mnel I don't think that's the case. Both densities should integrate to 1 which is not possible if one is strictly superior than the other.

Comment: is it possible that the `pro_vd==TRUE` group has some density (actually, it would need to be a lot of density) outside of the (0,1) interval that you're truncating the plot to?

Comment: @BenBolker you have the right answer. It actually has a very long, flat tail. Sorry for the inconvenience all.